# Adding value to MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, string, mongodb, text

currently i have data that needs to be inserted to mongodb. The data have been successfully inserted into mongodb, however there is some value that i would like to add to the data and append it into mongodb.

How can i do so? This is my code for `inserting data` into mongodb

```html
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('test_insert');
    collection.insert({ values:parsestring() }, function(err, docs) {
        collection.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log(format("count = %s", count));
        });
    });

    // Locate all the entries using find
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
        console.dir(results);
        // Let's close the db
        db.close();
    });
});

// "1,61,54,87,20,12/3/2016,8:39AM" this default value
function parsestring(str="1,30,40,50,20,10/10/2016,10:39AM")
{
    return str.split(",");
}
```

I would like to add value to the text string.

For example:
Machine Unit: 1,

Air Temperature °C: 30,

Water Temperature °C: 40,

Heat Temperature °C: 50,

Room Temperature °C: 20,

Date: 10/10/2016,

Time: 10:39AM

Comment: It would be better to use a `ODM` module such as `mongoose`

Comment: You already got comments on the identical question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390018/appending-text-string-to-mongodb-using-nodejs It still looks fishy and adding the data to an array or better an object is advisable instead of doing string manipulations.

Comment: @str what seems so fishy to you? this is a project that i am suppose to do. What do you recommend me to do then? How can i add data to an array/object?

Comment: Doing string concatenation and manipulation in a database that is perfectly capable of storing arrays and objects is fishy. You can [`$push` to an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or [`$set` an object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/).

Comment: actually with ´str.split(",")´ you get an array. So when your input string is always the same, you should be able to match each entry in this array to its corresponding "sensor data". Like @str said - there is no need to store the "label" as a string in the database, but you can write a function that amends the labels to each array entry when you **read** from the DB. (see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries - or https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like already mentioned in the comments, you should store your data as objects (or arrays). The line `str.split(",")` already returns you an array, which you store. In your code you also fetch your data as an Array. When you console.dir() your results, you could map your results.entries to a specific output string if you prefer.

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.dir(results); // <= results.entries
    // Let's close the db
    db.close();
});
```

See also:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map &
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries

However, if you want to store objects (e.g. for accessing data via identifier) you could simply do it like:

```
function parsestring(str="1,30,40,50,20,10/10/2016,10:39AM"){
  var dataArr = str.split(",");
  var dbEntry = {};

  dbEntry.machine = dataArr[0];
  dbEntry.airTemp = dataArr[1];
  dbEntry.waterTemp = dataArr[2];
  dbEntry.heatTemp = dataArr[3];
  dbEntry.roomTemp = dataArr[4];
  dbEntry.date = dataArr[5];
  dbEntry.time = dataArr[6];

  return dbEntry;
}
```

When returning a simple object from mongoDB, you won't need `.toArray()`